# Can I draw a arrow with different pointer style with konva？ such as trianglefilled or normal or triangle-not-filled

Tags: konvajs

Can I draw a arrow with different pointer style with konva？ Such as trianglefilled or normal or triangle-not-filled - see examples below:

Trianglefilled

[image: trianglefilled]

triangle-not-filled

[image: triangle-not-filled]

Answer (score 2):

`Konva.Arrow` doesn't support such drawing. But you can use [Custom Shape](https://konvajs.org/docs/shapes/Custom.html#page-title) to draw arrows like that.

I tried to draw your second arrow:

```js
const stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight
});

const layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

const shape = new Konva.Shape({
  points: [50, 50, 100, 100],
  pointerLength: 10,
  pointerWidth: 10,
  stroke: 'green',
  sceneFunc: (ctx, shape) => {
    // draw main line
    const points = shape.getAttr('points');
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(points[0], points[1]);
    ctx.lineTo(points[2], points[3]);
    ctx.fillStrokeShape(shape);

    // calculate attrs for pointer
    var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
    var dx = points[2] - points[0];
    var dy = points[3] - points[1];

    var radians = (Math.atan2(dy, dx) + PI2) % PI2;
    var length = shape.getAttr('pointerLength');
    var width = shape.getAttr('pointerWidth');

    // draw pointer
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.translate(points[2], points[3]);
    ctx.rotate(radians);
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(-length, width / 2);
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(-length, -width / 2);
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.fillStrokeShape(shape);
  }
});
layer.add(shape);

layer.draw();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@^6/konva.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```